# How do I install NAWK on Windows?

Tags: opencv, awk, gnu, nawk

I want to work with `OpenCVForAndroid` and a prerequisite for it is that I have Cygwin, Make and Nawk or Awk installed on my machine.
I was told, and was able to, install `make` on my machine using `CygWin`. However, I do not know how to install `Nawk` on my machine.

I am on Windows 7 32 bit. Can someone please help me with that ? :)

Comment: Why would you want nawk? gawk is a far superior awk and comes with cygwin. Just select it when you install cygwin. You can also install gawk for Windows directly, just google for it.

Comment: @EdMorton because Android Native Development Kit says use either Nawk or Awk that is why :) And yes, I saw that gawk comes with cygwin

Comment: @EdMorton http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Reqs

Comment: Nawk is Awk. Gawk is also Awk. Those requirements say `A recent version of awk (either GNU Awk or Nawk) is also required.` GNU Awk is gawk.

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Get gawk instead, either as part of cygwin or native to Windows from gnu.org.

Comment: Got NAWK. Still a few more things to do !!

Comment: @LittleChild Tell me you mean "Got Gawk", not "Got Nawk"!

Comment: Gawk comes with CygWin, I guess, by default